# Can't access the correct properties in base class with object involving multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, language-lawyer

Here's something that I can't figure out. I have the following code:

```
public interface IProject
{
    
}

public class ModuleProject : IProject
{

}

public class AllProject : IProject
{
    public ModuleProject ModuleData => new ModuleProject();
}

public interface IProjectInstance
{
    IProject Data { get; }
}

public interface IModuleProjectInstance : IProjectInstance
{
    new ModuleProject Data { get; }
}


public interface IAllProjectInstance : IModuleProjectInstance
{
}

public class AllProjectInstance : IAllProjectInstance
{
  
    IProject IProjectInstance.Data => Data;

    public AllProject Data => new AllProject();

    ModuleProject IModuleProjectInstance.Data => Data.ModuleData;
}

public abstract class Worker<T,VM>
where T:class, IProject
where VM:class, IProjectInstance
{
    private readonly T _data;
    protected Worker(VM viewModel)
    {
        _data = (T)viewModel.Data;  //fails to cast
    }
}

public class ModuleWorker : Worker<ModuleProject, IModuleProjectInstance>
{

    public ModuleWorker(IModuleProjectInstance viewModel) : base(viewModel)
    {
    }
}
```

When I run the below code:

```
 var projInstance = new AllProjectInstance();
 var moduleWorker = new ModuleWorker(projInstance);
```

The program crashes at `_data = (T)viewModel.Data` due to `InvalidCastException`.

> System.InvalidCastException   HResult=0x80004002   Message=Unable to
> cast object of type 'ProjectInstance.AllProject' to type
> 'ProjectInstance.ModuleProject'.   Source=ProjectInstance
> StackTrace:    at ProjectInstance.Worker`2..ctor(VM viewModel) in
> D:.net Samples project\August 2021\ProjectInstance\Worker.cs:line 15
> at ProjectInstance.ModuleWorker..ctor(IModuleProjectInstance
> viewModel) in D:.net Samples project\August
> 2021\ProjectInstance\Worker.cs:line 24    at
> ProjectInstance.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:.net Samples
> project\August 2021\ProjectInstance\Program.cs:line 16

It appears that `viewModel` is of the type `AllProjectInstance` and `AllProjectInstance.Data` is of the type `AllProject`, but `T` is `ModuleProject`, and hence the exception. Fair enough.

But let's say if I modify the code a little:

```
public abstract class Worker<T,VM>
where T:class, IProject
where VM:class, IProjectInstance
{
    private readonly T _data;

    protected Worker(T data) //this works!
    {
        _data = data;
    }

}

public class ModuleWorker : Worker<ModuleProject, IModuleProjectInstance>
{
    public ModuleWorker(IModuleProjectInstance viewModel) : base(viewModel.Data)
    {
    }

}
```

Then it works! Because in the `ModuleWorker` constructor, `viewModel` is inferred as the type of `IModuleProjectInstance`, and hence it's the `ModuleProject IModuleProjectInstance.Data` property inside the `AllProjectInstance` that has been called, hence no exception.

My questions:

1. If this behavior documented in C# specification?
2. What is the rational for such a design?
3. Is there a way to cast it in base class (`Worker<T,VM>`) so that the correct property is inferred?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with covariance?

Comment: @Sweeper, maybe you are right. Let me just remove the covariance tag

Comment: First you probably need some sort of constraint for `Worker<T,VM>` to indicate that `VM`'s `Data` property returns `T` then modify the class for whatever you are passing in for `VM` accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of `Worker`, `viewModel.Data` is a [member access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#member-access), and to evaluate this member access, a [member lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#member-lookup) needs to be performed. This is a member lookup of `Data` in the type `VM` (the type of `viewModel`) with 0 type arguments. Let's see how the member lookup is performed according to the spec.

(`T` refers to the type in which we are looking up the member, so = `VM` here. `N` is the name of the member that we are looking up, so = `Data`):

> First, a set of accessible members named `N` is determined:
>
> - If `T` is a type parameter, then the set is the union of the sets of accessible members named `N` in each of the types specified as a primary constraint or secondary constraint for `T`, along with the set of accessible members named `N` in `object`.
> - Otherwise, the set consists of all accessible members named `N` in `T`, including inherited members and the accessible members named `N` in `object`. [...]

`VM` is a type parameter, and the constraints for `VM` are `class` and `IProjectInstance`, so the first point applies. The set only has the property `IProject Data { get; }`.

The other steps only tries to remove elements from the set, and none of them applies in this case, so I won't go over them. In the end, the `Data` property declared in `IProjectInstance` is the result of the lookup.

Now, which of the implementations in `AllProjectInstance` corresponds to the implementation of `IProjectInstance.Data`? It is of course the explicit interface implementation for `IProjectInstance`

```
// This returns an AllProject object, causing the cast to fail
IProject IProjectInstance.Data => Data;
```

On the other hand, if you do `viewModel.Data` in the `ModuleWorker` constructor, the type of `viewModel` is `IModuleProjectInstance`. If you apply the same member lookup algorithm, you will see that this time it looks up the `Data` property declared in `IModuleProjectInstance`, and the corresponding implementation of that in `AllProjectInstance` is:

```
ModuleProject IModuleProjectInstance.Data => Data.ModuleData;
```

---

I'm not sure why you think this is unexpected. IMO it is natural for function members to not know about the expressions with which the callers call them. If you want `viewModel.Data` to resolve to `IModuleProjectInstance.Data`, that would require the `Worker` constructor to know that it has been called with an expression with compile time type `IModuleProjectInstance`. That said, this is not impossible to do in C# - you can require the caller to pass in an `Expression<Func<VM>>` and manipulate the expression tree to figure out its compile time type, and get the `Data` you want with reflection, but that's just overkill.

Rather than doing casting, it seems like you should make `IProjectInstance` generic:

```
public interface IProjectInstance<T> where T: IProject
{
    T Data { get; }
}

public interface IModuleProjectInstance : IProjectInstance<ModuleProject>
{
    
}


public interface IAllProjectInstance : IModuleProjectInstance
{
}

public class AllProjectInstance : IAllProjectInstance, IProjectInstance<AllProject>
{

    public AllProject Data => new AllProject();

    ModuleProject IProjectInstance<ModuleProject>.Data => Data.ModuleData;
}

public abstract class Worker<T,VM>
where T:class, IProject
where VM:class, IProjectInstance<T>
{
    private readonly T _data;
    protected Worker(VM viewModel)
    {
        _data = viewModel.Data;
    }
}
```

---

If you really can't make `IProjectInstance` generic, you can also try to get the type of the second type parameter with reflection, find the `Data` property, and get its value.

```
protected Worker(VM viewModel)
{
    var dataProperty = GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[1].GetProperty("Data");
    if (dataProperty != null) {
        _data = (T)dataProperty.GetValue(viewModel);
    } else { // fall back to your original approach
        _data = (T)viewModel.Data;
    }
}
```

This makes some assumptions about the subclasses of `Worker`, such as:

- its *direct* superclass is `Worker`
- `VM` does have an accessible `Data` property that returns something that can be casted to `T`. Right now, `ModuleWorker` would still compile if `IModuleProjectInstance.Data` got removed.

Comment: Is it possible to make the code to work _without_ making `IProjectInstance` a generic? It will involve too much change in my codebase.

Comment: @Graviton I've edited the answer to include a rather hacky solution. Warning: it's _really_ hacky. I've only tested it on the two pairs of types that you've shown here. It's full of assumptions about the other `XXXWorker` classes that you might have, so it probably will not work in your real code.